# How to create a XML property file in Java?

Tags: java, xml, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I"m working on **Selenium Webdriver** and the code I'm writing in **Java**.. In **Eclipse** running the scripts..

Currently i have many property files in my local directory and it is in the form of **test.txt** files and **test.properties**. And everything is a seperate files.

Example:

1.`login.txt` file contains the following details

```
loginUsername= test
loginPassword= 1234
url= https//: ....
```

2. `dropdown.properties` contains following values

```
visualizationId=Day,Week,Month,Quarter,Semester,Year,RD Tech Group,ICC,Center,Software Pack,Product,Project,Customer PRs,Severity,Priority
periodId=Last 4 Weeks,Last 52 Weeks,Date Range,Week Range,Month Range,Year To Date
classificationId=All PRs,External PRs,Internal PRs,Customer PRs
topographyId=Overall,Center,ICC,
swpacksId=ADVIP,ADVLEG,ADVSEC,Boot,H323,IBC,MULTI,None,OneOS_EAD,PROXY,SBO,SIP,TDRE,VoDSL
priorityId=Very Urgent,Urgent,Routine,Not Urgent,On Hold,Not Assigned
severityId=Blocking,Major,Minor,Cosmetic,OLD PR
projectId=/dev/v4.3/r4/e12sqq,BATS,1523 Business IAD & Business CPE,[CoCo2M],VQM
```

My doubt is how can i keep everything in the form of `XML` file and it should be generic and i should call wherever i want the xml property file.

Please help me for this scenario.

Comment: Could anyone suggest me the solution

Answer (score 0):

First create xml file as -

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project>

<logindetails id="1001">
        <username>abc</username>
        <password>mook kim</password>
</logindetails >

<staff id="1001">
        <firstname>abc</firstname>
        <lastname>efd</lastname>
        <salary>100000</salary>
</staff>

</project>
```

You can create nodes as per your requirement (like - staff,login in above xml)

Then you can get data from xml as per requirements-
e.g.-Suppose you want to get username from login then you can pass parameters (logindetails,username) to readXML method & get it as given below-

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;

    import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
    import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
    import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

    import org.w3c.dom.Document;
    import org.w3c.dom.Element;
    import org.w3c.dom.Node;
    import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
    import org.xml.sax.SAXException;


    public class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SAXException, IOException, ParserConfigurationException {
        A a = new A();
        String username = a.readXML("logindetails","username");
        System.out.println(username);
       //use username for webdriver specific actions
        driver.findElement(By......).sendkeys(username);
    }

        public String readXML(String searchelement,String tag) throws SAXException, IOException, ParserConfigurationException{
            String ele = null;
            File fXmlFile = new File("D://NewFile.xml");
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);

            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName(searchelement);


            Node nNode = nList.item(0);

            if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
                 ele=eElement.getElementsByTagName(tag).item(0).getTextContent();

            }
            return ele;
        }

    }
```

Comment: driver.findElement(By......).sendkeys(username ); i have given as By.id() it is returning null

Comment: edited code above. Please try again. Change- changed second parameter passed to readXML method. It should be "username" instead of "firstname" as "username" is under "logindetails" element in xml file.

Comment: I would recommend looking at Apache Commons Configuration library. Its helped me out in similar situations as yours.